# Mysql showing data constains two type of animals using intersect

Tags: mysql, sql, intersect

TheAnimals Table :
|Aname|Sex  |Type|Country|yearOfBirth| cNum |
|-----|-----|----|------ |-----------| ---- |
|Charly|male|Lion|Kenya|1990|12|
|Arthur|male|Bear|France|1980|1|
|Chloe|female|Magpie|France|1991|3|
|Milou|male|Leopard|France|1991|11|
|Tintin|male|Leopard|France|1991|11|

Thecages Table :
| cNum |   Function  | PathNum|
| ---- | ----------- | ------ |
|  11  | deer        | 10     |
|  1   | den         | 1      |
|  2   | aquarium    | 1      |
|  3   | small birds | 2      |
|  12  | deer        | 10     |

I use this query

```
Select cNum from theCages where cNum in (select cNum from theAnimals group by type having count(cNum)>=2);
```

It showing result :
| cNum |
| ---- |
| 11   |

How to show number of the cages that contains at least two animals of different types from this tables with query? The result should be empty because there is no cages that contains two type of animal

Answer (score 0):

To show the cage number with 2 differents type of animals, I imagine you could do like this :

```
select count(*) as cageNumber
FROM (
    select cNum, count(distinct `Type`) as typeNumber
    from Animals a 
    group by cNum
    having count(distinct `Type`) > 1
) cages
```